# Incorrect value when converting toString("G29")

Tags: c#, formatting

I have code to remove trailing zeros from a value before presenting it to the UI, however I have found that in some cases, instead of removing the zeros it alters the value.

eg: 123.400000000000000000 becomes 123.40000000000001

the code I am using is:

```
string value = "123.400000000000000000";
value = double.Parse(value).ToString("G29");
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can alter my code so it shows '123.4' instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're turning it into a `double` and, as everyone who's spent time dealing with floating point values will know, double precision values are not *infinite* precision values. The value selected is as close as it can get to what you provide but that's not always exactly what you want.

If you have a numeric-style string that you want to strip trailing zeros from, why don't you just strip the trailing zeros from it, with something like:

```
if (s.Contains(".")) {
    Regex regex = new Regex("\\.?0*$");
    s = regex.Replace(s,"");
}
```

The check for a `.` character is to ensure you don't strip trailing zeros off a number like `1000`. Once you know there's a decimal point in there, zeros (and the decimal point itself if it's _all zeros after that) can be stripped off the end with impunity. You can see it in action in the following complete console program:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string StripZ(string s)
        {
            if (s.Contains("."))
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex("\\.?0*$");
                s = regex.Replace(s, "");
            }
            return s;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(StripZ("123.400"));
            Console.WriteLine(StripZ("3.0"));
            Console.WriteLine(StripZ("7."));
            Console.WriteLine(StripZ("1000"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of that program is:

```
123.4
3
7
1000
```

Comment: Thanks for this, all of the answers have been really helpful to understand the issue and as a way of moving forward. Will use pax's regex to format my numbers instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `123.4` is not exactly representable in a binary floating point data type. The [closest double precision value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=123.4) is:

```
123.40000 00000 00005 68434 18860 80801 48696 89941 40625
```

The `ToString` method is rounding that to

```
123.40000 00000 0001
```

You should use a decimal data type instead of a binary data type. For instance:

```
string value = "123.400000000000000000";
value = decimal.Parse(value).ToString("G29");
```

However, if you are really starting with a string, and just wish to trim trailing zeros then it would perhaps be more prudent to do that using text processing.